# What does it mean while assigning a method to a reference variable?

Tags: java, methods

```
public class GC {
    public static GC doStuff() {
        GC newGC = new GC();
        doStuff2(newGC);
        return newGC;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GC gc1;
        GC gc2 = new GC();
        GC gc3 = new GC();
        GC gc4 = gc3;
        gc1 = doStuff(); // Question refers to this line
    }

    ...
}
```

A method represents an object's behavior while a reference variable represents a remote control to an object.But what does it mean while assigning a method to a reference variable?Why is it reasonable to link a behavior and a remote control?

Comment: You are not assigning a method, you are assigning the value returned by that method.

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger and observe the value of the variable after that statement executes.

Comment: Perhaps you could actually paste the code into the question as a code block!

Comment: The value returned, called newGC is a local variable,isn't it? Why can it be assigned to a reference variable in another method(i.e.main())?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dostaff() method will return the value that can be assigned to gc1. That means dostaff() return type is GC

Comment: The value returned, called newGC is a local variable,isn't it? Why can it be assigned to a reference variable in another method(i.e.main())?

Comment: newGC is a local variable it is declare in side a method. local variables can't access out side of the method it declared

Comment: I failed to access your link.

Comment: http://javaseeeedu.blogspot.com/2016/01/local-variable-global-variable-instance.html

Comment: you can use VPN called Pshipon

Comment: I have tried again and again, but still haven't found a valid solution to access google.

Comment: send me your email I will send you some notes

Comment: 550858270@qq.com

Comment: If it fix your problem you can mark this answer as correct one

Comment: Only if it is help you to fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Methods are like machines. You can put arguments in, some work is done inside, and then something comes out at the end. That what comes out of the method is the *return value* and can be assigned to another variable.

So in your case `gc1 = doStuff();` simply means to "start the machine" with name `doStuff`. It doesn't take any arguments, but produces a value at the end. This output is then used to be assigned to the variable `gc1`.

To give you a more concrete example, consider following code:

```
public static int twoTimesTwo() {
    int result = 2 * 2;
    return result; // output value of this method
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int value = twoTimesTwo();
    System.out.println(value); // prints 4
}
```

Here `twoTimesTwo` produces a value that is equal to `4` and exposes that value to the outside. That's why we can directly assign the result of the method to `value` which will print `4` in the end.